# Why can't I get null as an argument when switching screens in navigation?

Tags: android, android-navigation, android-navigation-graph, android-safe-args

I use `navigation` and `SafeArgs` to `switch screens` and `pass data`.

When data is selected on screen `A`, data is transmitted at the same time as screen switching.

However, there are times when screen `A` switches to screen `B` without any action.

I decided to send `null` in this case.

But I keep getting the following error:

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.lightweight, PID: 9555
    java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:612)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1130)
     Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:602)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1130) 
     Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at androidx.navigation.NavArgsLazy.getValue(NavArgsLazy.kt:54)
        at androidx.navigation.NavArgsLazy.getValue(NavArgsLazy.kt:35)
        at com.example.lightweight.fragment.WriteRoutineFragment.getArgs(WriteRoutineFragment.kt:20)
        at com.example.lightweight.fragment.WriteRoutineFragment.onViewCreated(WriteRoutineFragment.kt:44)
        at androidx.fragment.app.Fragment.performViewCreated(Fragment.java:2985)
```

***navigation.xml***

```
<fragment
        android:id="@+id/writeRoutine"
        android:name="com.example.lightweight.fragment.WriteRoutineFragment"
        android:label="fragment_write_routine"
        tools:layout="@layout/fragment_write_routine" >
        <action
            android:id="@+id/action_writeRoutineFragment_to_workoutListTabFragment"
            app:destination="@id/workoutListTabFragment" />
        <argument
            android:name="workout"
            app:argType="string"
            app:nullable="true" />
</fragment>
```

***In Adapter***

```
inner class ViewHolder(itemView: View, context: Context) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(itemView) {
        private val tv: TextView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.workout)

        init {
            tv.setOnClickListener { view ->
                val workout = tv.text.toString()
                val action: NavDirections = WorkoutListTabFragmentDirections.actionWorkoutListTabToWriteRoutine(workout)
                view.findNavController().navigate(action)
            }
        }

        fun bind(item: String) {
            tv.text = item
        }
    }
```

what's the reason?

Comment: What if you remove `app:nullable="true"` and pass a default `String` value for nullability cases.. Will you get the same error?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should add defaultValue of the workaround argument. Here because you have set `app:nullable="true"`, you should set `android:defaultValue="@null"`.

Modify the way you create workaround argument as follows:

```
<argument
   android:name="workout"
   app:argType="string"
   android:defaultValue="@null"
   app:nullable="true" />
```

More information: [Supported argument types - Navigation](https://developer.android.com/guide/navigation/navigation-pass-data?authuser=3#supported_argument_types)

Comment: This makes my app not compile, says I have too many parameters now.

Comment: Hey, man! Could you please explain your problem to me? @JPM

Comment: My issue was that I was trying to use a deep link with a custom Parcelable argument, and deep links only accept these parameters as strings, according to the link in the response: "Routes, deep links, and URIs with their arguments can be parsed from strings. This is not possible using custom data types such as Parcelables and Serializables as seen in the above table. To pass around custom complex data, store the data elsewhere such as a ViewModel or database and only pass an identifier while navigating; then retrieve the data in the new location after navigation has concluded."